# App crashing for some users due to kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-context

I've created a sharedPreference object which is being initialized in Application class.

Here's is the SharedPreference Object:

```
object PreferenceUtil {
    ...
    private lateinit var mPref: SharedPreferences

    fun init(context: Context) {
        if (!this::mPref.isInitialized)
            mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext)
    }
}
```

Also, my application class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        PreferenceUtil.init(this)
    }
}
```

And I'm accessing the sharedPreference in my MainActivity. For eg.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        if (PreferenceUtil.launchCount == 0) {
            //start WelcomeActivity
        }
    }
}
```

But my app is crashing for some users, with the exception of `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException` on mPref.

This is happening for very few users, for eg. only 0.05% of my total users.

Any idea why is this happening? Any help will be appreaciated.

Comment: Better Use `lazy` . Its not possible to tell what the problem with few lines of code .

Comment: It's just a simple initialization of sharedPreference object in Application class, and then it's used in other activities.
Also, as I've mentioned, it is only happening for 0.05% of the user or even less.
Is it possible that when the user updated the app, the application's class onCreate was not called, maybe because the app was still in background?

Comment: Are you using a BackupAgent? During Auto Backup, your app is launched in a restricted mode that uses a plain Application instance instead of your subclass. Any code that might be run during a backup cannot rely on your Application subclass being used. Normally there's nothing to worry about if you're not using Backup Agent, because Activities and Services aren't typically launched during backup.

Comment: Yes, backupAgent is enabled. Is it happening because of this?
Anyways, I fixed it by calling init in all activities that are using PreferenceUtil, the issue is solved for now.